# Unstring in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am trying to split a name field into three parts into first name, mid name, last name by using UNSTRING DELIMITED BY SPACES as follows

```
UNSTRING WA-NAME DELIMITED BY SPACES 
INTO WA-FIRST-NAME
     WA-MID-NAME
     WA-LAST-NAME
```

But if my name field has more than 2 spaces the remaining words are getting missed

`Example :       NAME          : M V S PAVAN
It is showing as WA-FIRST-NAME : M
                 WA-MID-NAME   : V
                 WA-LAST-NAME  : S`

But the fourth word `PAVAN` is missing how can i get that included in my third word. i.e, i want to include all the remaining words in `WA-LAST-NAME`

Comment: I have found it impossible to 100% automate.  Most names are cultural.  That is there are varying number of words in the last name depending on culture.  Even 3 word names could be just first name followed by pair of last names that are not hyphenated.  Having a human review a computer suggested first/middle/last split would depend on their expertise, and level of guesswork.  Go back to the individuals and ask them to enter their correct names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just solve the question "how can i get that included in my third word. i.e, i want to include all the remaining words in WA-LAST-NAME" (which may not be what you want) you can use different approaches but the best ones likely will use the POINTER (position in source field). It *may* uses an additional counter for the last item, leading to:

```
 UNSTRING WA-NAME DELIMITED BY ALL SPACES  *> just in case two spaces were used
 INTO WA-FIRST-NAME
      WA-MID-NAME
      WA-LAST-NAME COUNT STRPV *> *MOVE* the amount of target length
      WITH POINTER STRPS ON OVERFLOW
      ADD 2 TO STRPV           *> adding one to be after the text, another for space
      MOVE WA-NAME (STRPS:) TO WA-LAST-NAME (STRPV:)
```

Complete test:  http://tpcg.io/BYJXKL

As donPablo already pointed out you won't get an 100% automated correct name result...

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Use POINTER to keep track of where you are at, but split the UNSTRING into three UNSTRINGs.
Before each unstring loop using stored POINTER to first non-space (i.e. PERFORM VARYING from current pointer by 1 UNTIL value is not space OR end of string) and unstring from there.